# Hide and Show class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created an error class in CSS. When a GET request is made, the view is rendered on the client side but the error class shows up. I want to hide the error class when a GET request is made and show it when a POST request is made. 
See the image below:  [image]

My cshtml markup

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalSignIn", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "reg-page" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <input id="xss" type="hidden" name="idsrv.xsrf" token="model.antiForgery">
            <div class="reg-header">
                <h2>Login to your account</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
               </div>


            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "username", type = "email", required = "required", placeholder = "Email", name = "username" } })
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 checkbox login-remember">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" value=""> Stay signed in</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button btn-primaryng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn-u pull-right" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <hr>

            <h4>Forget your Password ?</h4>
            <p>
                no worries, <a class="color-green" href="">click here</a> to reset your password.
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div><!--/row-->
```

[image]

Comment: add a `hide` class along with `text-danger` initially..

Comment: it totally hide the class after i insert the text in it. it isn't show any error

Comment: How your error gets showed?

Comment: i uses unobtrusive j query it show error from server side

Comment: Remove the enclosing `<div class="alert alert-danger">` and add you styles to the `field-validation-error` class (which gets added to the `<span>` generated by `ValidationMessageFor()` when there is an error)

Comment: i applied your changing but there is one little problem @stephen Muecke

Comment: its show a span red when the email is texbox is empty or when it is correct email

Comment: yup i have removed it

Comment: Are you using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive,js`? There are multiple issues in your `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email()` - your need to remove `required = "required"` (thats HTML5 validation. You need to remove `name = "username"` (fortunately that does absolutely nothing because if it did you app would fail) and you should be using `[DataType(DataType.Email)]` and remove `type="email"`, and why are you changing the default `id=Email"` to `id="username"`?

Comment: thanks issue is now resolved @ Stephen